# Best way to edit an item in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I have an array of custom class and I want to make a change to one of the items in it.

```
var mainArray = [MainOrder]()

//Now imagine that mainArray has a bunch of different items in it.  

struct MainOrder:Codable {
    var time:Date?
    var order_id:String?
    var side:String?
}
```

What is the best way to do that? Right now I find the index then I move it into a new variable then I delete the item from the array and then add it back again like you see below. But I am sure this is better way to do this.

```
if let tempIndex = self.mainArray.index(where: {$0.side == "left"}) {
    var tempVar = self.mainArray[tempIndex]
    tempVar.time = Date()
    self.mainArray.remove(at: tempIndex)
    self.mainArray.insert(tempVar, at: tempIndex)
}
```

Comment: Can more than one object in your array have a matching `side`?

Comment: No it will be only one item. It should really be the order if that matches not the variable ‘side’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the following:

```
if let tempIndex = self.mainArray.index(where: {$0.side == "left"}) {
    mainArray[tempIndex].time = Date()
}
```

Here's a complete example demonstrating that this works:

```
struct MainOrder:Codable,CustomStringConvertible {
    var time:Date?
    var order_id:String?
    var side:String?

    var description: String {
        return "time: \(time), order_id: \(order_id), side: \(side)"
    }
}

var mainArray = [MainOrder]()

mainArray.append(MainOrder(time: nil, order_id: "hi", side: "left"))
print(mainArray)

if let tempIndex = self.mainArray.index(where: {$0.side == "left"}) {
    mainArray[tempIndex].time = Date()
}
print(mainArray)
```

Output:

> [time: nil, order_id: Optional("hi"), side: Optional("left")]
>   [time: Optional(2018-01-13 01:59:06 +0000), order_id: Optional("hi"), side: Optional("left")]

If you can guarantee there will always be an object in the array with the matching `side` value, you can force this all into one line:

```
mainArray[mainArray.index(where: { $0.side == "left" })!].time = Date()
```

But this will crash if your assumption is wrong. Be safe and do with the `if let`.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way to do it with one line of code. I tried to use the first function but that is a get only property

Comment: You need to get the index, if any, then you need to update the object at that index. That can't be done in one line because there might not be a matching index.

Comment: See the end of my updated answer for a risky way to do it all in one line.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: BTW - your question says "best way", not "one line".

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as class so it will be reference type

```
 class MainOrder:NSObject,Codable {
     var time:Date?
     var order_id:String?
     var side:String?
 }
```

Edit item directly

```
 var tempVar = self.mainArray[tempIndex]

 tempVar.time = Date()
```

Comment: It has to be a struct and value type not a reference type

Comment: I know that it can be done with a class but I want to know if it is possible using a struct. Also this is not the exact use case. When I have this deployed live things get really messed up when I edit different instances of the same array if it is a reference type opposed to a value type